# Isomorphism of a chain of structures

Tags: lo.logic

Consider an elementary chain of models of some first-order theory $T$:
 $$ (M_\alpha)_{\alpha < \kappa}, M_\alpha \prec M_\beta  \; {\rm for} \; \alpha < \beta .$$
Let also $(N_\alpha)$ be another elementary chain of models of the same theory.
Assume, that for every $\alpha < \kappa$ ($\kappa$ a cardinal) we have an isomorphism $f_\alpha: M_\alpha \to N_\alpha$. Is there a way to extend these isomorphisms to an isomorphism
$f: M \to N$, $M:= \bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} M_\alpha$, $N:= \bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} N_\alpha$, even if we don't assume that the restriction of $f_\beta$ to $M_\alpha$ for $\alpha < \beta$ is equal to $f_\alpha$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the following two linear orderings: $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathcal{N}=\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{N}^*$. (Recall that $\mathcal{L}\cdot\mathcal{L}'$ is the linear order gotten by replacing each point in $\mathcal{L}'$ with a copy of $\mathcal{L}$, and that $\mathcal{L}^*$ is just $\mathcal{L}$ with the order reversed.)

We can write $\mathcal{M}=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathcal{M}_n$ and $\mathcal{N}=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathcal{N}_n$, where $\mathcal{M}_n, \mathcal{N}_n\cong \mathbb{Z}\cdot n$, and such that each inclusion $\mathcal{M}_i\subseteq\mathcal{M}_j$ and $\mathcal{N}_i\subseteq\mathcal{N}_j$ ($i\le j$) is an elementary embedding.

In fact, the obstacle is precisely what you mention: that the isomorphisms between the components fail to glue together nicely.

---

Note that the part I'm leaving out is why the embeddings are elementary, and why $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are elementarily equivalent; but these are straightforward arguments with Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games.

Comment: Actually, I seem to recall that this question was asked on MO before, but I can't find it right now . . .

Comment: Under what additional hypotheses can we insure that the answer is positive?

Comment: There are no additional hypotheses that make the answer positive in general that I'm aware of, except for demanding that the isomorphisms extend each other. We could of course make do with some assumption like "$T$ is categorical in the relevant cardinality," but if you have an assumption like that lying around, why are you doing things with chains? :) In general, I suspect there's no hope unless you assume the isomorphisms do cohere; but maybe someone can set me straight on this.

Comment: Note that if your claim were true, we'd have (via Lowenheim-Skolem) an easy proof that $\aleph_0$-categorical theories are also $\aleph_1$-categorical, which is not true.

Comment: By a much, much more complicated argument. This is Morley's Theorem, and it is really quite remarkable (at least, I think so). I seem to recall that I learned Morley's Theorem from Sacks' "Saturated Model Theory," which I loved; but I don't have a copy lying around. There are some expositions available online which I quite like.

Comment: I have Sacks. But it is a pity that Morley's argument doesn't extend to non-first order theories.

Comment: (My previous comment was in response to a now-deleted comment, which I thought was a very good question; user 38200, should I delete it? If you say I should, I'll delete it and this comment.)

Comment: Oho! http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jbaldwin/pub/AEClec.pdf

Comment: No please don't delete it. But I cannot undo my deletion now.

Comment: I don't know the details, but Baldwin's book studies categoricity of infinitary theories, and of AECs in general, in depth; and I believe others have looked at categoricity in other settings. May I also recommend (every single thing in) the collection "Model-Theoretic Logics"? http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pl/1235417263

Comment: This is, of course, *not* to say that Morley's argument itself extends past first-order logics; just that the ideas of Morley's argument continue to be interesting in far more general settings, and that the study of *how much* of Morley's theorem remains true is incredibly fruitful. (Also, someone more versed in AECs and categoricity should totally jump in and say something with actual content. :))

Comment: I also have that, thanks. But I don't have much time. Here is another question: if we show that some AEC is quasiminimal excellent in the real world, and if we move to a model of set theory, does the same class remain so or no?

Comment: Hm. I don't really know anything about quasiminimal excellence, but glancing at Baldwin's definitions, it looks like the answer should be "yes" assuming all models of set theory involved are well-founded. However, there are lots of subtle annoyances which can show up here, so I wouldn't take my answer without much salt. (Actually, one minor observation: Baldwin defines quasiminimal excellence in terms of the full type, $tp$, whereas up until then he's used $tp_{qf}$. My answer is making the assumption that he means $tp_{qf}$; do you know if this is the case?)

Comment: Wait, ignore everything I just wrote: quasiminimal excellence has the form "for every special $C$ . . ." which means we have to worry about adding new special $C$s. Now, since every such $C$ is witnessed by a countable object, and that witnessing is (I think) absolute, it's certainly enough to demand that the forcing used be countably closed. However, in general, I now think that the answer may be "no;" but I think I'm going to bow out now, in the hopes that someone who knows what they're talking about can step in. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple counterexample. Let $T$ be the theory of sets with no additional structure. Let $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$ be the set $\omega+\alpha$ with no additional structure, and let $\mathcal{N}_{\alpha}=\mathbb{N}$ for all $\alpha<\omega_{1}$. Then if $\alpha\leq\beta$, then
$\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathcal{M}_{\beta}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{\alpha}$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathcal{N}_{\beta}$. Furthermore, $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}_{\alpha}$ for all countable ordinals $\alpha$. On the other hand, $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_{1}}\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$ has cardinality $\aleph_{1}$ while $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_{1}}\mathcal{N}_{\alpha}$ is countable. The same argument holds for chains whose length is a successor cardinal.

Comment: This is simpler; however, it's still useful to have an example where $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are both countable, *and* there is no forcing extension in which they become isomorphic.

Comment: ("and" should be "and therefore.")